# Windows AD 2008 - If I change a user account password and the user is still actively logged in can he/she change the password back?

Tags: security, windows-server-2008, active-directory

this is in regards to a windows server 2008 AD environment.
Apparently an Administrator user's password was changed.
But after a while he/she manages to change the password back.
There was no other users in the Administrators group.
If the user was still idly logged on, without being automatically locked (to retype the password) could the user have changed the password again?

Comment: If the change of password does not require the current password, then I would think it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be possible as when you go to type in your old password in the 'Change a password' dialog, it will only accept the one that AD has in the system. Unless they used a tool like Password Changer (loads available on Google) in my eyes it shouldn't have been able to change.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can, but only if the users whose password was changed is a Domain Administrator.

Domain Administrators can reset passwords without knowing the original, the user will lose any encrypted settings like saved credentials if you do this, but it does work.

[Here is the MSDN page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754395.aspx) explaining the process.